# how to search data from 2 different language in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have made a website with dual language in wordpress. english and arabic versions. now my problem is in the search. because i can't search any data on english version when im on the arabic version.

would it be possible to search a data from english version when im in the arabic version?

im a total newbie on this thingy. so im gonna need your help guys.

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any plugin for the translation

Comment: no. i just made to different website. because the translation got issues on some parts in the process.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin i have recently used this plugin in my wordpress i hope this will solve your problem.

```
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/
```

Comment: thank you farhan! but i already have the translated version of my english site to arabic which is done manually. my only problem is how to access the arabic data while searching on the english version. do you have any idea on that? thnx

Comment: well actually, i haven't touch any code from wordpress. its the default search code of wordpress.

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <header class="page-header">
     <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php
          
      get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
     ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

   <?php else : ?>